# Bloquear CSS especifico numa página especifica

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Estou usando o `WordPress`, e meu template atual possui alguns `CSS` que estão desconfigurando uma página que estou montando com um page builder.

Queria saber se tem como bloquear estes `CSS` nessa página especifica sem afetar as demais.

Exemplificando:

`p{word-wrap: break-word;}` via `style.css` para todas as páginas

Quero desabilitar o `p{word-wrap: break-word;}` na minha página especifica.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

Na página que você está construindo (com page buider) é possivel adicionar css customizado. Então basta sobrescrever a propriedade `word-wrap`. Você pode colocar o valor padrão, ficando:

```
p{word-wrap: normal;}
```

Comment: Pode colocar um `<style>` na `<head>` da página com esse código abaixo do `style.css` que irá ignorar o código.

Comment: E se o CSS for `p{margin: 20px;}`? Como eu anulo o `margin`?

Comment: De acordo com o [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp), a tag p utiliza os seguintes estilos (por padrão): `p {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}` Para modifica-los basta proceder da mesma maneira como o anterior. No link mencionado você pode encontrar os estilos padrão de cada tag html.